# Return multiple values from a method in C#

Tags: c#

Issue is am not able to get all the values, only first record is available i.e `PMDES1_01` the other return values are not captured, please help with this code

```
public class DataxAero
{
    //Create new method to get data from xAero database
    public static string GetData(string ORDNUM_10)
    {
        string PMDES1_01 = "";
        string DESCRPTN_104 = "";
        string PRTNUM_10 = "";
        string ORDREF_10 = "";
        string TNXDTE_01 = "";
        //Create connection
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=true;");

        //SQL Command
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  ...............", con); 

        //Open connection
        con.Open();
        //to read from SQL Server
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            PMDES1_01 = dr["PMDES1_01"].ToString();
            PRTNUM_10 = dr["PRTNUM_10"].ToString();
            DESCRPTN_104 = dr["DESCRPTN_104"].ToString();                
            ORDREF_10 = dr["ORDREF_10"].ToString();
            TNXDTE_01 = dr["TNXDTE_01"].ToString();

        }

        //close connections
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();

       //get the values

        return PMDES1_01;
        return PRTNUM_10; (get error here Unreachable code detected)
        return DESCRPTN_104;             
        return ORDREF_10;
        return TNXDTE_01;
```

Comment: You ought to create a plain class object that stores those values and return an instance of that.

Comment: Create a new type that has a property corresponcing to each element you want to returned, create a new insteance of it, populate it from the data reader, and return that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods in .Net don't support multiple return statements. If you wish to return multiple values, you must do it by returning a *collection*. Here's an example:

```
public static List<string> GetData(string ORDNUM_10)
{
    //snip...

    return new List<string> { PMDES1_01, PRTNUM_10, DESCRPTN_104, ORDREF_10, TNXDTE_01 };
}
```

Your calling code can then extract the values from the returned list.

Comment: Thanks dan this was super sweeeet...You saved my life

Comment: Heh, you're welcome... but in general I'd suggest you follow @JonSkeet's answer. :)

Answer (score 11):

It looks like this is trying to return *related* values - a number, a description, an order reference etc.

You should create a class to encapsulate all those values, change the return type of the method to that class, and then at the end your method create an instance of that class from the values retrieved from the database.

```
public static Order GetOrder(string orderId)
{
    // Use a "using" statement for each resource (database connection etc),
    // so that the resources are released even if there's an exception
    using (...)
    {
        // Do the query here...

        // Note "if" rather than "while" - we're only going to return
        // a single result anyway
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            string manufacturer = (string) dr["PMDES1_01"];
            int partNumber = (int) dr["PRTNUM_10"];
            string description = (string) dr["DESCRPTN_104"];
            int orderReference = (int) dr["ORDREF_10"];
            string text = (string) dr["TNXDTE_01"];
            return new Order(manufacturer, partNumber, description,
                             orderReference, text);
        }
        // No results!
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've guessed at the real data types, but I doubt that they're *actually* all strings. Also note the variable names, changed to be more readable and comply with .NET idioms.

Comment: Yup. Better answer. OP should prefer this approach. :)

Answer (score 9):

In C# you can only return one value.

Ways around this are:

1. Return an object which encapsulates those different values.
2. Use [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) parameters
3. Use [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) parameters
4. Return a [tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)
5. Return an IEnumreable and return items one by one via [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question, the way to do that would be to pass them as `out` parameters. However, I agree with Chris Sinclair that if they're all related, you should create an object to contain all of those values in one object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of strings. Method has only one return.